# Ubuntu/Unity: unminimize all windows

Tags: unity, window

How could I unminimize all windows (at least of the current workspace)? I basically want to show on the desktop all the opened windows.

Comment: @Mr Shunz suggested I comment and give the idea to use a CCSM (official Canonical.com, even though it sounds like that) tool to navigate your difficulty, even though nobody else so far would seem to publicly try that much to deal with that pain, and thus giving the answer might risk public humiliation of a research and development idea, but +MrShunz did not reply promptly and things could get heavy so I am going to just follow their only advice and direct advise (apparenty they can moderate in a second but cannot approve in a second).

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have minimized all the windows by using ctrl-super-D, you can unminimize them by using again ctrl-super-D.

Comment: Just [super](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_%28keyboard_button%29#Linux_and_BSD)-D is working for me. Although, I'm using [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).

Note to self: Replace Windows logo on that key...

Comment: Unfortunately, your assumption is not what I want. I want to unminimize all windows whatever means they were minimized. I don't think that there is any shortcut that does what I want. An idea would be to use wmctrl, parse all windows and unminimized them. I'm wondering if there is an option in compiz plugin to do what I want.

Comment: @gregoiregentil "Load CompizConfig Settings Manager, click and unclick "Opacify" (may work for other extension options) checkbox, and all your windows will be Unminimized together." —https://askubuntu.com/posts/1087332/revisions ...I added the answer there too (repeating it/answer verbatim as a comment here, moderation came for the kill pronto but did not stay even a second to talk/ask), but got speedily "moderated"/"judged and executed" immediately before you could reasonably be expected to read.